# No puedo ejecutar appium debido al Chromedriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

Hola a tod@s tengo un error en la ejecución de appium en el chromedriver. Es devido por la versión pero no se como arreglarlo, me podéis ayudar ?

Este es mi código java

```
public class InicioPrueba {

    public static AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;
    //public static AndroidDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android");

        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
        //driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
        driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
           System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("HolaMundo");

        driver.quit();


    } 
}
```

y aquí se arroja el siguiente error en consola:

> ```
>    Chrome version on the device: Chrome/76.0.3809.111
>     Visit 'https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver.md'
> ```
>
> to troubleshoot the problem.
>           Failed to start Chromedriver session: A new session could not be created. Details: session not created: Chrome version must be
>   between 71 and 75
>             (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.17134 x86_64)
>           Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
>           System info: host: 'CR3533006DC0109', ip: '192.168.0.19', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_65'
>           Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
>           remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to
>   automate Chrome version because it is too old for this version of
>   Chromedriver.
>           Chrome version on the device: Chrome/76.0.3809.111
>           Visit 'https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver.md'
>   to troubleshoot the problem.
>           Failed to start Chromedriver session: A new session could not be created. Details: session not created: Chrome version must be
>   between 71 and 75
>             (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.17134 x86_64)
>               at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\x57119ga\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:826:9)
>               at asyncHandler (C:\Users\x57119ga\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:447:37)
>               at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
>           Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'

Answer (score 0):

Ya esta solucionado. Pongo un comentario para que lo sepáis como lo he echo, por si alguna vez os pasa

Si tenemos problemas con el driver por su versión, tenemos que irnos a esta ruta y coger nuestra versión del Chrome del móvil https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Y cambiaríamos la versión en esta ruta
**C: \ Usuarios \ {nombre de usuario} \ AppData \ Roaming \ npm \ node_modules \ appium \ node_modules \ appium-chromedriver \ chromedriver \ win**